# `Web Deploy` errors - databases can not be created

Tags: asp.net, webdeploy

I am having trouble using Web Deploy. In particular:

1. I'm not sure what username/password/serviceurl/site/application to use in the publish profile.
2. I'm also confused about what I need to include in my connection strings.

I either get an error saying that one of my databases can not be created or this:

> Error 1   Web deployment task failed.((12/3/2012 4:57:59 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)
>
> (12/3/2012 4:57:59 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
> An error was encountered when processing operation 'Create Directory' on (the url)
> I/O error occurred.

I'm using the provided "Arvixe".

Comment: Your question is both too broad (errors?) and too specific (specific hosting provider). I think you best bet is to obtain support from your hosting provider. The other questions you have should be self-evident while developing your site (how did you develop your db site without conn strings?). Moving your site to production usually means changes these settings (again, info from your host).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so it turns out I had everything correct.

The problem was that the server required me to create the databases manually.

After that I could run my code to generate tables and populate them with data.

The problem was getting the databases initially created.